# When drawing 2D, its two lines are connected / joined/ combined?

Tags: word-choice

When drawing two lines that makes 2D (two dimensional), these are connected / joined/ combined / verb else?

I would like to say that when we draw two lines (in two directions) and we connect (?) them together, we get two dimensional body.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an option for your question:

> When we draw two lines and **have them *meet* at a point**...

Answer (score 2):

First off, in mathematical terms, a **line** is extends for infinity in both directions, a **ray** extends to infinity in one direction but has an end point, and a **line segment** has two end points. In everyday terms, we call line segments *lines* (and things that aren't actually straight too).

An **intersection** is where two of these cross and can be described as where they *intersect*, *meet*, *cross*, and so on. A **vertex** is the point where two line segments or rays meet to form an angle, and is often referred to as a *corner*.

[image: Diagram I made]

Mathematical terms are **bolded* while general terms are *italicized*
*Italized* are general terms.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But actually I need active sentence, as I mentioned in my question. Can I say "If we connect two lines to two different directions and we meet them, then we get two dimensional shape" ?

Answer (score 1):

Of your three possibilities, the generally correct choice would be connected. I think it unlikely that "combined" would be used. And, "joined" would also be less commonly used, but it would work. There are a number of other words and phrases that would be more commonly used.

A couple of examples might help.

- The lines meet at a point, thus forming a two-dimensional body (alternates: figure, shape)
- The lines are connected at a point, thus  . . .(etc)

I will add this: my answer applies if you are talking about lines in a mathematical context (math, trigonometry, geometry, physics), where lines are considered one-dimensional and generally infinite.
If, instead, you were speaking as an artist, or art was your context, you could more comfortably use "combined", although I would still recommend "meet". Art does not regard lines in the same way that math does. Based on the words you have used, I believe you are speaking in the context of a mathematical application.

Comment: Thank you. But actually I need active sentence, as I mentioned in my question. Can I say "If we connect two lines to two different directions, and we meet them, then we get two dimensional shape" ?

Comment: The sentence you have just written does not work, for several reasons. I will try to help by telling you how I might say it: "When two lines meet, then we get a two dimensional shape." Or, "When two lines are not parallel, they will meet at a point, and then they will form a two dimensional shape." You would not "connect" the two lines. The lines would "meet", and they do that by their nature. "Connecting" indicates that you have taken action in the process, and that is not what is happening, by the nature of lines. {Too many characters now - hope this helps! :)}